# Condition in v-bind:Style

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```html
<div>
  <figure :style="{ 'background': 'url(' + item.main_featured + ') center no-repeat' }">
</div>
```

I want the style attribute `background` to return a color if the URL from API is `undefined`

Example:

If `item.featured_photo` is not `null`:

```html
<figure style="background: url('localhost:6969/image.img') center no-repeat">
```

If `item.featured_photo` is null:

```html
<figure style="background: #FFF">
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Use condition in V-bind:style VueJS:

```
v-bind:style= "[condition ? {styleA} : {styleB}]"
```

Here is the minimal example,

```html
<figure :style="[item.main_featured ? {'background': 'url(' + item.main_featured + ') center no-repeat'} : {'background': '#FFF'}]">
```

If you need **Parent-Child-Conditions**, then this is the magic:

```
v-bind:style= "[condition_1 ? condition_2 ? {styleA} : {styleB} : {styleC}]"
```

In short of:

```
if (condition_1) {
   if (condition_2) {
      return styleA
   } else {
      return styleB
   }
} else {
  return styleC
}
```

Answer (score 47):

The previous references were very good, but for me what really worked was this:

```
<input type="text" 
v-bind:style=" boolVariable ? 'border: 1px solid orange;' : 'border: none;' ">
```

In the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions

Regards!

Answer (score 11):

Feed Git's answer is perfect, here's another example with multiple attributes. Just separate with commas:

```
:style="[printing ? {'margin' : '0px 0px 20px 0px', 'min-height': '830px', 'box- shadow': 'none', 'border': 'none'} : {'margin': '0px 0px 20px 0px', 'min-height': '830px'}]
```

The form follows (for someone like me who's new at this):

```
:style="[boolVariable ? { true } : { false }]
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a computed property for this:

```
<figure :style="'{ background: `${background}` }'">

...

data () {
    return {
        item: {
           featured_photo: null
        }
     }
},
computed: {
    background () {
        return !item.featured_photo ? '#fff' : `url(${item.featured_photo}) center no-repeat`
    }
},
methods: {
    setPhoto(val) {
         this.item.featured_photo = val
    }
}
```

Edit:

I'm making a bunch of assumptions here with your API and routes. This is a rough stab at generalizing it:

```
<figure :style="'{ background: `${getBackground('main_featured')}` }'">
<figure :style="'{ background: `${getBackground('featured_photo', 1)}` }'">
<figure :style="'{ background: `${getBackground('featured_photo', 2)}` }'">


...

methods: {
     async getBackground (type, index) {
          let r = await axios.get(`/images/${type}/${index}`).then(r => r.data.background)
          return r || '#fff'
     }
 }
```

Comment: Anyway shorter bro !!

Comment: Yeah probably, how are you making the API call?

Comment: I fixed it. Let view my answer below. Anyway Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me

```
<div :style="[ myboolean ? { backgroundImage: `url(${group.backgroundImage.sourceUrl})` } : null ]">
```

Answer (score 6):

In case someone needs `multiple conditional style bindings` on one element use this:

```
:style="[ 
    condition1 ? { 'width': '50%' } : '', 
    condition2 ? { 'height' : '20rem' } : ''
]"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're iterating through an object, you can use a method. In such cases when the style is dependent on a property in the object, this is the only option I have found .... none of the options above work.

```
<div v-for="thing in things">
   <div :style="'{ background: `${background(thing)}` }'"></div>
</div>
...

data () {
    return {
        item: {
           featured_photo: null
        }
     }
},
methods: {
    background (thing) {
        return thing ? 'red' : 'black'`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Background Color you have to pay special attention
**you can't use**

```
:style="[ isDark ? {background-color: 'black'}: {background-color: 'white'}]"
```

it won't work you can use the **backgroundColor**

```
:style="[ isDark ? {backgroundColor: 'black'}: {backgroundColor: 'white'}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

In quasar framework

```
V-bind:style=" $q.screen.lt.md ? 'height:600px' : ''"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use not just Boolean conditional but also numbers. this worked for me.

```
:style="{ transform: `translate(${x}vw)` }"
```