# Vue inline conditional if?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following piece of code:

```
    <div
        :id="'object' + object.id""
        :style="'position:absolute !important; width:' + object.width + '% !important; height:' + object.height + '% !important;'">
    <div
```

This works fine and renders nicely as it should.

I now want to add conditional stuff in there. Something like

```
if object.background == 'solid'
 background-color: #ffffff;
endif
```

I tried achieving this via the Vue inline if, which gave me this:

> [object.background == 'solid' ? background-color: #ffffff important; :
>   '']

But that just gave a lot of errors, which lead me to think I'm tackling this all wrong.

What would the correct approach be for me to achieve having short conditional statements in my style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a computed property that returns a style object.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
    background: 'solid',
  },
  computed: {
    styleObj() {
      return {
        position: 'absolute !important',
        width: `${this.width} !important`,
        height: `${this.height} !important`,
        background: this.background === 'solid' ? 'green' : 'yellow',
      };
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div :style="styleObj">    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe there is no need to create a computed property for this. You can bind the object directly to the `style` attribute.

Comment: The computed property has advantages like caching. It's also much easier to read than when it's in the template.

Comment: @BillCriswell You're right. I completely forgot about caching.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this should be marked as a duplicate of this question: [Condition in v-bind:Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455909/condition-in-v-bindstyle-vuejs)

However, this method is documented only for classes binding, on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

That said, you ask:

> What would the correct approach be for me to achieve having short conditional statements in my style?

I don't think this is a correct approach. I mean, the correct approach would be to write css classes and apply them conditionally, since those are the documented methods, leave this for cases when you have to apply direct styling to override all other styles that apply to the element in question.

Other correct approach would be to use `data`, `props`, or even a `computed property` or `method`.

Also, you can have both `style` and `:style` attributes and vue will mix them for you, so you can define base style on the normal attribute and "other stuff" on the style binding.

But as i say, leave this for extreme cases where you really need this on the style attribute.

Comment: @StevenB. I think that may apply to "leave this for cases when you have to apply direct styling to override all other styles..." not explicitly, but still! hahaha