# vue.js ternary style binding - invalid expression: Unexpected token ']'

Tags: vue.js, coffeescript

```
partNav = Vue.component('part-nav', {
  data:
    navItems: [
      {
        subItems: [
          {...}
          {...}
        ]
      }
      {...} # another object in navItems array
    ]

  template: '
    <div
      v-for="(navItem, navItem_index) in navItems"
      :style="[ navItem.subItems ? { height: (1.3 + 2 * 0.75) * navItem.subItems.length + \'rem;\' } ]"
    >
    </div>
  '
})
```

> invalid expression: Unexpected token ']' in ...

How can I apply this style binding - if navItem in v-for has subItems array then apply style (height of one element multiplied by subItems length)?

As help I've been used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455909/condition-in-v-bindstyle-vuejs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```js
:style="navItem.subItems ? { height: (1.3 + 2 * 0.75) * navItem.subItems.length + 'rem' } : {}"
```

A ternary needs all 3 arguments (hence the name). There's also no need for the square brackets.

I've retained your original condition of `navItem.subItems`. That'll only work if the `subItems` array can be missing (i.e. `null` or `undefined`). An empty array doesn't count as falsey so if that's the case you're interested in you'll need to adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You could drop the ternary and just use a check

```
:style="navItem.subItems && { height: (1.3 + 2 * 0.75) * navItem.subItems.length + \'rem;\' }"
```

If you want to check if the array is not empty then you can do this

```
:style="navItem.subItems && navItems.subItems.length && { height: (1.3 + 2 * 0.75) * navItem.subItems.length + \'rem;\' }"
```